# Javascript to validate pass word while typing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate the password match while typing however, its not working can someone please tell me the error

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>password change </title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</div>
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword"  />
</div>
    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"its not working"_ - in what way? Do you get an error message? Does it misbehave? Please provide details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include a reference to JQuery in order to use it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>password change </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</div>
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword"  />
</div>
    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```